# How can I find many local maxima in a noisy image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How do you go about figuring our multiple max in a 2D image where the max aren't necessarily all the same height? I have found that the `imregionalmax()`, `imextendedmax()`, and `findpeaks()` functions aren't necessarily that helpful because they give many local max that are really just maxes within the background noise. I tried

```
bw=array > imdilate(array,[1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1]);
```

but that also is kind of limited for the same reasons (same thing with expanding the matrix that it uses).

Comment: Related question (noise-free case): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856197/how-can-i-find-local-maxima-in-an-image-in-matlab

Answer (score 3):

Noise is indeed a problem in image analysis where you try and find intensity maxima. As with any other task in image analysis, you can improve the final results with pre-processing of the image and post-processing of the results of the algorithm.

As pre-processing step before the local maximum detection, you de-noise the image, i.e. you filter the image to suppress some of the spurious maxima (`imfilter` is a function you may want to look into).

The de-noising never gets rid of all the noise, so when you do the local maximum detection, you still pick up a number of unwanted maxima. Thus, you apply some kind of heuristic to distinguish between 'good' and 'bad' local maxima. For example, you can apply an intensity threshold, below which you discard all maxima.

You find a nice review of this here:  *Smal et al. Quantitative comparison of spot detection methods in fluorescence microscopy. IEEE Trans Med Imaging (2010) vol. 29 (2) pp. 282-301*

Answer (score 1):

here is a code that [finds 2D peaks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37388-fast-2d-peak-finder) in noisy data. The code thresholds the data, median filters it, smooths it with a user defined filter, thresholds again, and looks for local maxima at relevant pixels. The code also offers a simple and robust way to estimate the threshold needed.

Answer (score 0):

I always try median filter first (`medfilt2`). It removes small noise while maintaining most contours.

If you already got candidates - why not filter them with some tests? Like volume under peak or distance to next peak.