# how to find local maxima in image

Tags: matlab, local, feature-detection

The question is about feature detection concept.
I'm stuck after I finding the corner of image and I want to know how to finding the feature point within the computed corners.

Suppose I have grayscale image that have data like this

```
A = [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
      1 3 3 3 1 1 4 1;
      1 3 5 3 1 4 4 4;
      1 3 3 3 1 4 4 4; 
      1 1 1 1 1 4 6 4;
      1 1 1 1 1 4 4 4]
```

if I use

```
B = imregionalmax(A);
```

the result would be like this

```
B = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
      0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0;
      0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1;
      0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1;
      0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1;
      0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

The question is how do I **pick the highest peak** inside max local region (in sample how did I chose 5 from 3 and 6 from 4)?

My idea was using B to detect each region and use `imregionalmax()` again but I'm not good at coding and I need some advice or other ideas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of other easy ways to implement a 2D peak finder: [`ordfilt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html) or [`imdilate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html).

### `ordfilt2`

The most direct method is to use `ordfilt2`, which sorts values in local neighborhoods and picks the n-th value. ([The MathWorks example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html#f6-478708) demonstrates how to implemented a max filter.) You can also implement a 3x3 peak finder with `ordfilt2` by, (1) using a 3x3 domain that *does not include the center pixel*, (2) selecting the largest (8th) value and (3) comparing to the center value:

```
>> mask = ones(3); mask(5) = 0 % 3x3 max
mask =
     1     1     1
     1     0     1
     1     1     1
```

There are 8 values considered in this mask, so the 8-th value is the max. The filter output:

```
>> B = ordfilt2(A,8,mask)
B =
     3     3     3     3     3     4     4     4
     3     5     5     5     4     4     4     4
     3     5     3     5     4     4     4     4
     3     5     5     5     4     6     6     6
     3     3     3     3     4     6     4     6
     1     1     1     1     4     6     6     6
```

The trick is compare this to `A`, the center value of each neighborhood:

```
>> peaks = A > B
peaks =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

### `imdilate`

Image dilation is usually done on binary images, but *grayscale* image dilation is simply a max filter (see [Definitions section](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html#bse5fkv) of `imdilate` docs). The same trick used with `ordfilt2` applies here: define a neighborhood that does not include the center neighborhood pixel, apply the filter and compare to the unfiltered image:

```
B = imdilate(A, mask);
peaks = A > B;
```

**NOTE**: These methods only find a single pixel peak. If any neighbors have the same value, it will not be a peak.

Answer (score 1):

The function [imregionalmax](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/images/ref/imregionalmax.html) gives you the 8-connected region containing the maximum and its 8 neighbours (i.e. the 3x3-regions you are seeing). You could then use [morphological operations](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) with the same 3x3 structural element to thin out those regions to their centers. E.g.

```
 B = imregionalmax(A);
 C = imerode(B, ones(3));
```

or equivalently

```
 B = imregionalmax(A);
 D =  bwmorph(B, 'erode');
```

Alternatively you could write your own maximum finding function using [block-processing](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/images/ref/blockproc.html):

```
 fun = @(block) % your code working on 'block' goes here ...
 B = blockproc(A, ones(3), fun)
```

But most likely this will be slower than the built-in functions. 
(I don't have the toolbox available right now, so I can't try that out.)

Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856197/how-can-i-find-local-maxima-in-an-image-in-matlab?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706528/how-can-i-find-many-local-maxima-in-a-noisy-image).