# Using the output of harris corner detector to detect corners (A new issue arises)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision, corner-detection

I am using the Harris corner detector code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862225/implementing-a-harris-corner-detector). However, the final output "H" has very large negative values and the maximum value is 0. I initially convolve the image with the two 3x3 Sobel masks to extract Ix and Iy matrices. Then the Harris corner detector function uses the Ix and Iy matrices to compute Harris

Here's my code:

```
IxMask = [-1, 0, 1; -2, 0, 2; -1, 0, 1];
IyMask = [1, 2, 1; 0, 0, 0; -1, -2, -1];
Ix = conv2(double(imread('imageName.jpg')), IxMask);
Iy = conv2(double(imread('imageName.jpg')), IyMask);
A = Ix.^2;
B = Iy.^2;
C = (Ix.*Iy).^2;
lambda = 0.04;

H = (A.*B - C) - lambda*(A+B).^2;
```

All of the values of the H matrix are negative and some of them are extremely large negative numbers. Is something wrong with it? If so, I haven't been able to figure out what is the problem with my code. Could you please help me out with that?

Here's the original image:

[image: The original picture]

Here is an output of my function without applying any Gaussian kernel on the `Ix` and `Iy` matrices which has negative values:

[image: R matrix shown (All values are negative)]

Here is an output of the function **after applying a Gaussian kernel** with Sigma 1-3 on the `Ix` and `Iy` matrices. After applying a Gaussian kernal the **minimum value** of the R matrix will be 0!!
This is however the values of the R matrix were are negative and the **maximum value** was 0!

[image: R matrix shown (All values are positive)]

I'm totally confused that how I can detect the corners. I may note that I don't have Computer Vision toolbox of MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

The equation for `C` seems wrong.  Try:

```
C = (Ix.*Iy).^2;  % was .^4
```

Also, you generally smooth `Ix` and `Iy` with a Gaussian. MATLAB filters `A`, `B` and `C`, with the 2D kernel `k = w(:)*w(:)'` where `w=fspecial('gaussian',[1 5],1.5);`.

And you probably want to use `conv2(...,'same')`, or similarly with `filter2`.

Then if you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can use `BW = imregionalmax(cornerness,8);` to get a 2D mask of the maxima (corners). If you don't have the toolbox, follow [this answer for finding local maxima in a 2D matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218892/2778484).

Comment: Thank you. I just applied the changes you mentioned, but still the H matrix has extremely large negative values and no positive value and I don't know how to detect the corners. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: You are having negative values because hessian matrix above is producing strong edge responses which are negative, depending on your image, if you don't  smooth it with a sufficently large smoothing filter, this might happen. You are also not making any boundary control for image values(Derivatives; Ix, Iy.). I produced only negative results for a standard image of Lena before smoothing and some positive values after smoothing. This might be the case with your image, too. Good luck!

Comment: Could you please check the question again? I am confused now. I don't know what you mean by not making any boundary for Ix and Iy.

Comment: @Amir Filter the `A`, `B` and `C`. With the 2D kernel `k = w(:)*w(:)'` where `w=fspecial('gaussian',[1 5],1.5);`. Then compute `H`, which will give you the "cornerness" metric. Then if you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can use `BW = imregionalmax(cMetric,8);` to get a 2D mask of the maxima (corners). If you don't have the toolbox, follow [this answer for finding local maxima in a 2D matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22218892/2778484).

Comment: @Amir Also note that you will probably need to apply some thresholding based on cornerness quality otherwise you'll have a lot of weak corners.

Comment: Thank you so much. The issue is resolved now. I will update the topic when I have some time. Sorry for posting this here, but can I be in contact with you more direct? I couldn't find your E-Mail address on your profile.

Comment: @Amir I'm glad the issue is fixed now.  If the way you fixed it differs significantly from the answer, you can post your own answer and accept it yourself, however I would of course be happy to update my answer if the fix is related to the suggestions in my answer. Keep in mind that you shouldn't edit the question much, because the answers will generally address the question at the time it was posted. This is why questions need to be clear and concise, and if distinct new questions arise, a new question can be posted.

Comment: @Amir For example, the original code was using the wrong exponent, and some additional processing was required.  I believe I've addressed most of the issues, but again, I'd be glad to update my answer so it is complete. Also, it's best to keep communication public so that it can benefit as many people as possible. There is a chat function of this site, however, if you want to chat.

Comment: @Amir I am facing the same issue. How did you fix it?

Comment: @AbhishekKannan Presumably he took the suggestion in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974432/using-the-output-of-harris-corner-detector-to-detect-corners-a-new-issue-arises/22974964?noredirect=1#comment35211133_22974964), with some thresholding of the cornerness output.

Answer (score 2):

Found this post as I was having the same issue. I was able to fix the problem and think it's worth posting my solution here.

In your computation of the corner response
H = (A.*B - C) - lambda*(A+B).^2;

(A.*B - C) is the determinant 
(A + B) is the trace
This is incorrect, because **you are not taking the determinant and trace of the M matrix.** Instead, you are simply taking the determinant and trace about each pixel location. When doing this, we should expect many strong negative values for the corner response, since **the determinant will be zero and the resulting response function becomes H = -lambda(trace(M)^2)**.

Proof: (Ix^2 .* Iy^2) - (Ix .* Iy).^2 = (Ix^2 .* Iy^2) - (Ix^2 .* Iy^2) = 0.

The correct solution would involve generating the elements of the M matrix first:

1. At each pixel location, sum up Ix^2, Iy^2, Ix*Iy over some window around that pixel to generate the M matrix
2. Compute determinant and trace for the M matrix computed in step (1)
3. Compute Harris Response using the elements of the M matrix

Example code:

```
IxMask = [-1, 0, 1; -2, 0, 2; -1, 0, 1];
IyMask = [1, 2, 1; 0, 0, 0; -1, -2, -1];
wMask = [1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1]; 

Ix = conv2(double(imread('imageName.jpg')), IxMask);
Iy = conv2(double(imread('imageName.jpg')), IyMask);

Ix2 = Ix.^2;
Iy2 = Iy.^2;
Ixy = (Ix.*Iy);

M_11 = conv2(Ix2, wMask);
M_12 = conv2(Ixy, wMask);
M_22 = conv2(Iy2, wMask);

det_M = (M_11.*M_22 - M_12.*M_12);
trace_M = (M_11 + M_22);
H = det_M - lambda.*(trace_M.^2);
```

Note that I used a uniform weight function. In reality, we'd use a gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for that in the Computer Vision System Toolbox called `detectHarrisFeatures`.

Comment: So, is it a confirmation that the negative values are correct in the R matrix?
I need to implement the function by myself to detect the features. Do you have any resources for that?

Comment: Could you please check the question again? I have edited my question.